# How to use system() command with administrator properties?

Tags: python-3.x, module, system

Say I have a simple program: (module being some module to import)

```
from os import system
try:
    import module
except:
    system('py -m pip install module')
    import module
```

My problem is, the module that i need to install needs administrator privileges.
How do I launch py in administrator? 
I have tried things like:
system('py',adminstrator), and stupid stuff like that hoping one of them to work, but to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instructions [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/05cce5f6-3c3a-4bb8-8b72-8c1ce4b5eff1/how-to-run-a-program-as-adminitrator-via-the-command-line?forum=w7itproappcompat) to create a `sudo.cmd` file, make it available in your system path, and then you can gain Administrator privileges in your Python script with:

```
system('sudo py -m pip install module')
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have a single or multiple command line only in python, so i could send it to someone and they just run the command?